# Could not open ServletContext resource -- except there is no reference to the resource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

When opening tomcat I get: HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception

The root cause is listed as:

```
IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
```

What I don't get is *why* Tomcat tries to open that resource when I haven't got any references to it. If I search for it I get: *"No occurrences of 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet' found".*

Comment: Have you had a look in the web.xml?

Comment: Could you provide your web.xml?

Comment: Ah you're right, my search for mvc-dispatcher-servlet didn't turn anything up, but apparently that's a standard name for DispatcherServlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a registered `DispatcherServlet` like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>some-name</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Will try to find a Spring XML context file named `<name of the servlet>-servlet.xml` in `WEB-INF`.

Your `DispatcherServlet` must be registered under the name `mvc-dispatcher`.